# Finding Minimum Value In An Array - C++

Tags: c++

This program:

1. Takes 5 numbers (working)
2. These 5 numbers are processed using `for` and `if` (not working)
3. Displays the minimum value (not working)

Source:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    int i, a[5], min;

    cout << "Enter 5 numbers: " << endl;

    for (i = 0; i <=4; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        if (a[i+1] < a[i])
            min = a[i+1];
        else
            min = a[i];
    }

    cout << "Minimum number is: " << min << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a much simpler implementation.

```
int min=INT_MAX;
for ( i = 0; i <= 4; i++ ) {
    if ( a[i] < min ) {
        min = a[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the minimum value, you're simply comparing two successive values against each other:

```
1 5 4 3 2
```

So you're comparing `1` against `5`, then `5` against `4`, then `4` against `3`, then `3` against `2`.

What you *should* be doing is comparing each successive value **against the lowest value found so far**.

So start with a ridiculously **HIGH** minimum for `min`, then look for a lower one:

```
int min = MAX_INT; // Largest possible integer

for (..) {
    if (min > a[i]) { // Is min more than new value?
        min = a[i];   // Yes! New min value!
    } // if
} // for
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main() {
    int i, a[5], min;
    cout << "Enter 5 numbers: " << endl;
    for ( i = 0; i <=4; i++ ) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    min = a[0];
    for ( i = 1; i < 5; i++ ) {
        if ( a[i] < min ) {
            min = a[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "Minimum number is: " << min << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You compare two consecutives indexes and not the min, Remplace `if ( a[i+1] < a[i] )` by if ( min > a[i] ) and initialize correctly min (=a[0] for exemple).

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
    using namespace std;

    main() {
        int i, a[5], min=INT_MAX;
        cout << "Enter 5 numbers: " << endl;
        for ( i = 0; i <=4; i++ ) {
            cin >> a[i];
        }
        for ( i = 0; i <= 4; i++ ) {
            if ( a[i] <min) {
                min = a[i];
            }

        }
        cout << "Minimum number is: " << min << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
    int step_1= fmax(a[0], a[1]);
    int step_2 = fmax(a[2], a[3]);
    int step_3 = fmax(step_1, a[4]);
    int step_final = fmax(step_3, step_2);
    cout<<step_final;
```